# Glade error: <id> is not accessible

Tags: user-interface, ocaml, glade

This is my first question on stackoverflow. 
I searched over the web to no avail, and I really can't figure out what's wrong, so here we go.

I am trying to add a dialog window to [Marionnet](http://www.marionnet.org). The window information is mostly contained in the glade file, with some bits modified from code. [lablgtk](http://lablgtk.forge.ocamlcore.org/) is the framework that allows gtk2 (and thus glade-generated files) to be used with the ocaml language.
The application is successfully compiled, however it generates this runtime error at launch:

```
(marionnet.byte:5384): libglade-CRITICAL **: glade_xml_build_interface: assertion `wid != NULL' failed
Fatal error: exception Failure("Glade error: GtkDialog:dialog_RELATIVIZATION is not accessible.")
Raised at file "pervasives.ml", line 22, characters 22-33
Called from file "gui.ml", line 617, characters 9-85
Called from file "gui/gui_menubar_MARIONNET.ml", line 356, characters 17-49
Called from unknown location
Called from unknown location
```

The error suggests that the class constructor doesn't exist or something like that, but I checked multiple times and I didn't spot any typo in the identifiers I used. What am I missing here? What does the exception actually mean? 
To prove that there are no typos or missing identifiers, I'll show you the file contents.
The file gui.ml is generated by lablgladecc2, which reads the contents of gui.xml (the glade file). This is an extract from gui.xml:

```
  <widget class="GtkDialog" id="dialog_RELATIVIZATION">
    <property name="visible">True</property>
    <property name="title" translatable="yes">Relativization</property>
    <property name="resizable">False</property>
    <property name="modal">True</property>
    <property name="destroy_with_parent">True</property>
    <property name="icon">marionnet-launcher.png</property>
    <property name="type_hint">dialog</property>
    <child internal-child="vbox">
    [...]
```

So the id "dialog_RELATIVIZATION" is there. Indeed, the generated gui.ml file has the correct class and method:

```
[...]
class dialog_RELATIVIZATION ?(file="gui.glade.patched") ?domain ?autoconnect(*=true*) () =
  let xmldata = Glade.create ~file  ~root:"dialog_RELATIVIZATION" ?domain () in
  object (self)
    inherit Glade.xml ?autoconnect xmldata
    val toplevel =
      new GWindow.dialog_any (GtkWindow.Dialog.cast
        (Glade.get_widget_msg ~name:"dialog_RELATIVIZATION" ~info:"GtkDialog" xmldata))
    method toplevel = toplevel
    val dialog_RELATIVIZATION =
      new GWindow.dialog_any (GtkWindow.Dialog.cast
        (Glade.get_widget_msg ~name:"dialog_RELATIVIZATION" ~info:"GtkDialog" xmldata))
    method dialog_RELATIVIZATION = dialog_RELATIVIZATION
[...]
```

This is the code where I try to access the window:

```
let rel_dialog = new Gui.dialog_RELATIVIZATION () in
rel_dialog#toplevel#set_title (s_ "Relativization");
   rel_dialog#label_frequency#set_label (s_ "Frequency");
   rel_dialog#label_convergence#set_label (s_ "Convergence");
   rel_dialog#checkb_existing_machines#set_label (s_ "Apply to existing machines");
```

Google didn't help me, and I did not find good documentation about lablgtk. Does anyone know what the exception means and what the cause could be?